# Updated: Memory Location being outputted instead of desired string

Tags: c++, arrays, string, function, segmentation-fault

->Please see my edited question below the horizontal divider:

I was trying to return a string array from a function to another function. The code compiled successfully; however, it failed upon execution. I have included my code below:

```
    string Occupant::LoadDataFunction()
    {
        string array[5] = {"hello", "you", "are", "a", "human"};

        return array[5];
    }

    void Occupant::LoadData()
    {
        string loc_array[5];
        loc_array[5] = Occupant::LoadDataFunction();

        string park_array[5];
        park_array[5] = Occupant::LoadDataFunction();

        string lease_array[5];
        lease_array[5] = Occupant::LoadDataFunction();
    }
```

When I debugged the code, I found out that the problem was in the return statement of the function:

```
    return array[5]
```

The debugger had the following output:

> Signal = SIGSEGV (Segmentation Fault)
>
> this = { Occupant * const | 0x61ff2f} 0x61ff2f
>
> array = {std::_cxx11::basic_string< char, std::char_traits, std::allocator> [5]}

Can someone tell me what is wrong with my return statement, why it is causing a segmentation error? Thanks

** *I know there are many other similar questions on the web, but none of them involved a segmentation fault in the return statement Therefore, I would appreciate it if this question is not marked as a duplicate. If you need any more information, just inform me in the comments box. Thanks for your help!*

---

EDIT Thanks everyone, I didn't notice that glitch I just fixed it. I actually wanted to return the entire array, I did it with pointers this time. Here's my code:

```
    string* Occupant::LoadDataFunction()
    {
        string* array = new string[5];
        array[0] = "hello";
        array[1] = "hello";
        array[2] = "hello";
        array[3] = "hello";
        array[4] = "hello";

        return array;
    }

    void Occupant::LoadData()
    {
        string **loc_array = new string*[5];
        loc_array[5] = Occupant::LoadDataFunction();

        string **park_array = new string*[5];
        park_array[5] = Occupant::LoadDataFunction();

        string **lease_array = new string*[5];
        lease_array[5] = Occupant::LoadDataFunction();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            cout << &loc_array[i] << " : location" << endl;
            cout << &park_array[i] <<  " : parking" << endl;
            cout << &lease_array[i] <<  " : leased" << endl;
        }
    }
```

The problem now is that when I run the code, rather than printing hello fifteen times in total, it prints the memory address. Here's what I got:

> 0xf56d50 : location
>
> 0xf56df8 : parking
>
> 0xf56ea0 : leased
>
> 0xf56d54 : location
>
> 0xf56dfc : parking
>
> 0xf56ea4 : leased
>
> 0xf56d58 : location
>
> 0xf56e00 : parking
>
> 0xf56ea8 : leased
>
> 0xf56d5c : location
>
> 0xf56e04 : parking
>
> 0xf56eac : leased
>
> 0xf56d60 : location
>
> 0xf56e08 : parking
>
> 0xf56eb0 : leased

I expected a "Hello" word outputted wherever a memory address is outputted. Can anyone explain this now? Thanks for all your answers!

Comment: The index of array starts from `0`, so `array[5]` is out of the bound.

Comment: Your return type is `string` but `array` is an `array` of `string`.

Comment: Is using `std::Vector` an option?

Comment: Sorry, @Matt, but I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Regarding your note, you can still have the same problem and get different behaviour. One problem is using `arr[5]` to mean the whole array when it's actually an out-of-bounds element, which is a pretty common problem. Despite the behaviour resulting from someone else doing that differing from your behaviour, the real answer is understanding how to use arrays and it helps both you and them. However, you do also have other issues like trying to return an array, which can't be done directly with C arrays. I suggest using `std::array` because it's a lot more "normal".

Comment: No, unfortunately, I'm not allowed to use `std::Vector`, @A.S.H.

Comment: @NewbietoProgramming an array can be thought of as a collection of pointers to the things in the array.  So you want to return a pointer to a string.  Do you know the size of the array at compile time (is it constant)?  Or is it dynamic?

Comment: `string Occupant::LoadDataFunction()` means the function returns a single string. It does not return an array

Comment: @Matt an array is not a collection of pointers,  it is a collection of the things in the array, and those things are contiguous in memory..  You can point to any of those things but such pointers are not part of the array

Comment: You can't create an array of five things and then try to access the sixth one.

Comment: @Matt My array has a constant size. I fixed that problem, but I've landed into another one. Please see my updated question above. Thanks!

Comment: @NewbietoProgramming -- `std::array<std::string, 5>`  That is what you are trying to look for.  Forget about the pointers.  Also there is no need for any calls to `new` in your program.  From what you posted, everything can be value-based, and not dynamically created using `new`.

Comment: Sorry, @PaulMcKenzie, I'm not sure how `std::array<std::string, 5>` works. Could you please provide an example?

Comment: @NewbietoProgramming -- It will work.  Even if you read it out loud, doesn't it sound like what you're asking for?  "An array of 5 strings".

Comment: @NewbietoProgramming After your edits, I posted two possible solutions, one using `std::array`, and the other using a non-STL container approach.  Regardless of which one, both lack any usage of pointers, which really is my main point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To return an array, use [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), as a `std::array` is copyable and assignable, unlike a vanilla array.

```
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>

typedef std::array<std::string, 5> Array5Strings;

Array5Strings LoadDataFunction()
{
    Array5Strings ret;
    std::fill(ret.begin(), ret.end(), "hello");
    return ret;
}
```

Also, I used `std::fill` to quickly set the items to "hello".

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/0BdwUH)

---

If for some weird reason you can't use `std::array`, then the other alternative is to create a `struct` that contains an array of 5 strings, and return the `struct`.  A `struct` is copyable, thus can be returned directly from a function.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

struct Array5Strings
{
   std::string sArray[5];
};

Array5Strings LoadDataFunction()
{
    Array5Strings ret;
    std::fill(std::begin(ret.sArray), std::end(ret.sArray), "hello");
    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    Array5Strings val = LoadDataFunction();
    std::cout << val.sArray[0]; // prints the first value
}
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/dblhXu)

Regardless of which you choose, note that there are no pointers involved.

Comment: The first choice works just fine, @PaulMcKenzie, I'm just not allowed to use vectors. This is so easy compared to pointers that I'm wondering why my prof never taught me this :/

Comment: @NewbietoProgramming -- Actually, the `struct` version is a stripped-down version of `std::array`.  In essence, the `struct` version is what `std::array` actually does.  The difference is that `std::array` has a few member functions, has `operator [ ]` overloaded to access the items, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The range of an array of size N is from 0 to N-1. So the 5 is out of the range. And you may want to return an array as a result, but the array is constructed in the function `LoadData`, after the function is executed, the array is invalid. You may use dynamic allocation for your purpose or use a global variable.

When you use the dynamic allocation array, you can just use `string*` instead of `string**`, and you should release the allocated memory.

Comment: Also the return statement?

Comment: I just fixed that issue, you were right @cstur4, I actually wanted to return the entire array. Please see my update in my question above :)

Answer (score 2):

You are accessing the arrays using out of bounds index.

When you have an array declared as:

```
    string loc_array[5];
```

the valid indices are `0` - `4`.

Use of

```
    loc_array[5] = Occupant::LoadDataFunction();
```

is cause for undefined behavior. I suspect you meant to use:

```
    loc_array[4] = Occupant::LoadDataFunction();
```

Similarly, you need to use:

```
    park_array[4] = Occupant::LoadDataFunction();
```

and

```
    lease_array[4] = Occupant::LoadDataFunction();
```

You also need to change `Occupant::LoadDataFunction`.

```
string Occupant::LoadDataFunction()
{
    string array[5] = {"hello", "you", "are", "a", "human"};
    return array[4];
}
```

**Update**

The updated implementation of of `Occupant::LoadDataFunction` is better but there are still problems.

1. Each time the function gets called, you are allocating an array of `string`s. It's not clear whether that's the intention. If that's the intention, then the calling code has to take responsibility for deallocating that memory.
2. The calling code still suffers from out our bounds memory access. The line

   ```
   string **loc_array = new string*[5];
   ```

   allocates memory for `5` `string*`. The valid indices for `loc_array` is still `0` - `4`. Hence,

   ```
   loc_array[5] = Occupant::LoadDataFunction();
   ```

   suffers from out of bounds memory access problem. It's not clear how you wish to use the return value of `Occupant::LoadDataFunction`. Hence, I am not able to suggest a way to solve the problem.

   The lines

   ```
   park_array[5] = Occupant::LoadDataFunction();

   lease_array[5] = Occupant::LoadDataFunction();
   ```

   suffer from the same problem.

Comment: I think OP wants to return all of the array members at once

Comment: @M.M that's a definite possibility. I'll let the OP clarify.

Comment: Sorry, @RSahu, that's what I wanted to do, but I've fixed that problem and ended up in a new one. Please see update above.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @RSahu! I keep making such small errors without noticing it. Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 2):

Try returning `array[4]`. There is no `array[5]`, since arrays start at index 0.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I recommend you [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).